# Gostaria de saber como passar o value de um radius via post com ajax ou jquery

Tags: html, ajax

Precisava de ajuda para passa qualquer value de um desses `inputs` via Ajax ou jQuery:

```
<input type="radio" id="valorum" name="valor" value="38,70" ></br>
<input type="radio" id="valordois" name="valor" value="71,40" ></br>
<input type="radio" id="valortres" name="valor" value="118,80" ><br><br>


$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

Como eu faria pra passar um desses `values` dentro desse Ajax? Ou não tem como, ou há outro método de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Pegue os valores pelo id.

```
<script>
var value = $("#valorum").val();
$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        data: { suaVariavelDoServidor: value },
        url: "test.js",
        dataType: "script"
});
</script>
```

Caso queira enviar todos os valores como array:

```
var values = []
$("input").each(function(){
     values.push(this.value);   
});
$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        data: { suaVariavelDoServidor: values },
        url: "test.js",
        dataType: "script"
});
```

Comment: Os campos já tinham um `id` cada. :)

Comment: Mas o script funciona ;)

Comment: Não seria melhor editar a resposta?

Comment: sim seria. : - )

Comment: Hmm, acho que to entendendo!!
No caso o valor do radius sera enviada pra dentro da url:test.js ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar essa linha para pegar o valor do botão que está selecionado, substitua o ID **myForm** pelo o ID de seu formulário

Exemplo de como o código deve ficar

```
var campoRadio =  $('input[name=valor]:checked', '#myForm').val();
$.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   data: { campoRadio: campoRadio },
   url: "test.js",
   dataType: "script"
});
```

O ideal seria se você pudesse utilizar o **post** no lugar do **get**

Comment: Marcos, eu nao submeto nem um formulário nesse código.
Somente clicando no radius eu nao conseguiria enviar seu value para o test.js não ?